# What is wrong with the following ajax code?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I am trying to pass the id of 'this' object from ajax call to django view but i am getting the following error in my broswer :

[image: 404 error]

as i am beginner to both django and ajax that is why there could be errors in the code.

here is my code :

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from librarysystem.models import Users
from django.http import JsonResponse

def index(request):
    template = 'librarysystem/Elib.html'
    return render(request,template)

def validateForm(request, id):
    data = {
       'isTaken' : Users.objects.filter(username__iexact=request.GET.get(id,None)).exists(),
       #'emailidTaken' : Users.objects.filter(emailid__iexact=emailid).exists(),
      }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^registered/$',views.create_user),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="Index"),
    url(r'^validate(?P<id>)/$',views.validateForm),
    #url(r'^article/$', views.Article, name="Article"),
]
```

**ajax code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
        //var emailid = $('#emailid').val() ;
        $.ajax({
             url: '/librarysystem/validate/this.id/',
             data: {
         'this.id': this.value,
        //'emailid': emailid,
             },
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function(data){
                    if (data.isTaken){
                       $('#error').html(this.id + ' Already taken.').css('color','red');
                    }else
                       $('#error').html('');
             }
        }) ;
    }
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#retrypassword').keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
   $("#username, #emailid, #password, #retrypassword").keyup(validateForm);
});
</script>
```

thanks for your kind replies :)

Comment: the URL might not exist. I assume.

Comment: /librarysystem/validate/this.id/ ? this.id looks like it should be replaced with a real id value?

Comment: As I said in your other question, you need to learn how to use the browser tools to see what the actual error is. In this case though it's obvious, as axel points out.

Comment: @axel do you mean to say /librarysystem/validate/this.value/ ???

Answer (score 0):

> the problem is it's not finding the location .. some times
>   it may cause even path is correct but port is not...

eg:
 if you're using localhost:8080 but its finding in localhost:8000
I recently had this issue then i changed property file in my project.

Answer (score 0):

The attached screenshot gives a clear answer, the requested URL is not found (error 404). As I mentioned in my comment above this is because you use a simple string for the AJAY URL: `'/librarysystem/validate/this.id/'` instead of concatenate the static and dynamic part of the url:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/librarysystem/validate/' + this.value + '/',
  // the rest of your code....
  data: {}
});
```

But from what I see in your code example this might not be the only problem - in your given code there is no reference to '`this.value`.